# Can I bind shared libraries with "gcc -llibnamehere", in addition to static ones?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linker, shared-libraries

Two projects:

- The loader, a standalone executable (only loads modules)
- any module, a shared library (librainbowdash.so) (there can be many modules)

Now, the module is linked with `-lpthreads`, but I get some weird errors which make me think pthreads is bound as a shared object only, and when the loader loads a module pthreads are not being loaded. (debugging with GDB is impossible, that kind of errors).

I thought the `-l` switch only allows static libraries? Does it? Doesn't it?

Comment: It doesn't. `-l` is only for convenient path lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-l` specifies library names. It is up to the linker to resolve the library names into static libraries or shared objects to be linked against as appropriate. And it is the loader's job to load any shared libraries used.

Comment: That's what I thought. Is there a way to enforce it being a static library? I guess there is libpthreads.so in the .a version available..

Comment: Depends on the linker. With GNU ld you can use `-static` before the `-l` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the ld and gcc manpages, it is possible to define 'option groups', I might be a bit rusty, but it should go something like

```
gcc -o yourprog -Wl,-Bstatic yourprog.c -lstatic_lib -Wl,-Bdynamic -ldynamic_lib
```

The exact incantation is probably wrong.

From experience, passing the full path of the static library has proven to be much less of a headache than figuring out the exact form of the above mentioned incantation.

That being said, I doubt you would gain much benefit by statically linking pthreads.

I think you might also use

```
gcc -pthread ...
```

as well.

Using a simple -static will make the output and all its  dependencies static. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your shared library points to `lpthread` in a wrong location. Using `ldd` tool e.g., `ldd libfoo.so` is often a very effective way to find such linking problems.